# Making a variable global makes it a tuple

Tags: python, floating-point, global-variables, tuples

In my program, I have several variables within functions that I need to call on in other functions. To do this I made the variables I need global (example:)

```
def Vcmi1(Vcm, VcmU, Vi1, Vi1U, Pi1, Pi1U, Pi2, Pi2U, m1, m1U, m2, m2U):
global Vcmi1
global Vcmi1U
Vcmi1 = Vi1-Vcm
Vcmi1U = (Vi1U+(((Pi1U+Pi2U)/(Pi1+Pi2))+((m1U+m2U)/(m1+m2))))*Vcmi1
return Vcmi1, Vcmi1U
```

However, when I use them in a later function, these variables are tuples instead of floats and they cannot be multiplied with other floats (example:)

```
def initial_momentum_cm_1(m1, m1U, Vcmi1, Vcmi1U, Vcm, VcmU, Vf2, Vf2U, Pi1, Pi1U, Pi2, Pi2U, m2, m2U):
Pcmi1 = Vcmi1*m1
Pcmi1U = (((Vi1U+(((Pi1U+Pi2U)/(Pi1+Pi2))+((m1U+m2U)/(m1+m2)))))+(m1U/m1))*Pcmi1
return Pcmi1, Pcmi1U
```

I'm relatively new to python so I'm not 100% sure how the global command works (found out about it last night for this purpose). How can I make that tuple into a float and still be able to use it outside of its function?

Comment: Some quick pointers, you shouldn't be naming your function and variable the same `Vcmi1`. When you do `return Vcmi1, Vcmi1U` that's where you're probably making it a tuple. `global` does not have anything to do with it

Comment: Also, to note you seem to passing all the variables in to the second function, despite making some of them `global`

Comment: Ahh thanks so much! So would adding `Vcmi1, Vcmi1U = select_choice()` on the next line outside of the function solve this problem? And I assume you refer to this part `def initial_momentum_cm_1(m1, m1U, Vcmi1, Vcmi1U, Vcm, VcmU, Vf2, Vf2U, Pi1, Pi1U, Pi2, Pi2U, m2, m2U):`. So if they're global, I don't have to include them in the function in order to use them?

Comment: Quick question, these two look like something out of collision momemtum equations, but I really can't figure them out. Are these two to run in squence, `def Vcmi1` and then `def initial_momentum_cm_1` ? or the other way around?

Comment: Yes that's correct, it runs `def Vcmi1` and then `def initial_momentum_cm_1`. In the entire program it runs 4 different kinds of "Vcm" for the initial and final velocities of objects 1 and 2, and then applies them correspondingly to 4 matching functions for the momentum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `return v1, u1`, it returns two values. So if you call this function like so

```
 result = Vcmi1(...)
```

the two values get packed into a tuple and `result = (v1, u1)`. An alternative to this is to have them unpacked directly like this

```
 Vcmi1, Vcmi1U = Vcmi1(...)
```

And then you can pass them onto the next function in the next line. In summary, if your execution happens in `main`, it should look something like this (I've renamed your first function so that its easier to understand)

```
def main():
    for caseNumber in xrange(4):
        Vcm = raw_input("Enter vcm for case#{}:".format(caseNumber))
        #Calculate the two velocities and store them in 2 variables
        Vcmi1, Vcmi1U = calculate_velocities(Vcm, VcmU, Vi1, Vi1U, Pi1, Pi1U, Pi2, Pi2U, m1, m1U, m2, m2U)

        #Now simply pass these two variables onto the next function
        p1, p2 = initial_momentum_cm_1(m1, m1U, Vcmi1, Vcmi1U, Vcm, VcmU, Vf2, Vf2U, Pi1, Pi1U, Pi2, Pi2U, m2, m2U)
```

The `global` is not needed in this case. The namespaces for the variables are valid until the end of `main` (or whichever your calling function is)

The only reason you want to use global is if you don't want to pass so many arguments.

Comment: Thank you so much! Ran part of the code doing this and it seems to have solved the problem. I'll add it to the entire thing and run it to see how it goes.